# (From Milne's notes) Prove that $F(x^2)\cap F(x^2-x)=F$

Tags: field-theory, proof-explanation, extension-field

Here is the question and the proof.
[image][image]

I cannot understand why in the final step we have $[F(x):E]\le [F(x):F(f(x))]$. Is that the fact that we have a tower $F(x)/E/F(f(x))$? But if that is true, how can I see that? Thanks for any help!

Comment: The previous line says that $E$ contains $f(X)$, which implies that $F(f(X)) \subseteq E$.